# Error 422 Unprocessable Entity in laravel with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I have the next error in a application of Laravel:

```
422 Unprocessable Entity
```

The request is:

```
_token  LgJFXgWTMLtGcax4k2BoU86U2x1MEL7fqXrvl3i0
txtDetalle  qqq
txtSucursal 123
```

And the server response it's:

```
{"txtSucursal":["The txt sucursal must be at least 4 characters."]}
```

Generates the following error:

```
"NetworkError: 422 Unprocessable Entity -"
```

The code is the next:

[image: Request]

Answer (score 3):

You've set a validation rule that `txtSucursal` have a minimum of four characters, and the string `123` only has three. Thus, Laravel returns a validation error, which has a HTTP status code of 422.

Comment: How would you gracefully catch this error and display the errors using the returned JSON response so the 422 does not appear, or is this ok?

Comment: @RobertRocha The 422 errors in Laravel *automatically* include detailed JSON data about the validation errors that were encountered.