# Why am I getting a 422 error code?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vue-resource

I am making a POST request, but unable to get anything besides a 422 response.

**Vue.js client code:**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: {
    form: {
      companyName: '',
      street: '',
      city: '',
      state: '',
      zip: '',
      contactName: '',
      phone: '',
      email: '',
      numberOfOffices: 0,
      numberOfEmployees: 0,
    }
  },

  methods: {
    register: function() {
      this.$http.post('/office-depot-register', this.form).then(function (response) {

        // success callback
        console.log(response);

      }, function (response) {

        // error callback
        console.log(response);

      });
    }
  }
});
```

**Laravel Routes:**

```
Route::post('/office-depot-register', ['uses' => 'OfficeDepotController@register', 'as' => 'office-depot-register']);
```

**Laravel Controller:**

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'companyName' => 'required',
        // ...
    ]);

    // ...
}
```

Comment: From what I can tell, Laravel sending back a 422 means that the request didn't fulfill validation requirements. (E.g. Missing required field, other validation failures) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34966690/error-422-unprocessable-entity-in-laravel-with-ajax Since you have `companyName` required, but have it as an empty string, that could well be what's causing your issue.

Comment: That's exactly it. Leave your comment as an answer and I'll accept it. 

Comment: Glad I was able to help :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Laravel allows you to define certain validations on fields it accepts. If you fail these validations, it will return `HTTP 422 - Unprocessable Entity`. In your particular case, it appears that you're failing your own validation tests with an empty skeleton object, since `companyName` is required, and an empty string does not pass the required validation.

Assuming the other fields are similarly validated, a populated data object should solve your issue.

```
data: {
  form: {
    companyName: 'Dummy Company',
    street: '123 Example Street',
    city: 'Example',
    state: 'CA',
    zip: '90210',
    contactName: 'John Smith',
    phone: '310-555-0149',
    email: 'john@example.com',
    numberOfOffices: 1,
    numberOfEmployees: 2,
  }
}
```

Comment: How would you gracefully catch this error and display the errors using the returned JSON response so the 422 does not appear, or is this ok?

Comment: @Robert Rocha you can do `.catch(error => { console.log(error.response) })`