# Laravel 5.5 FormRequest Validation with Ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel, response, laravel-5.5

FormRequest was working well with Laravel 5.4, but on Laravel 5.5 its showing `400 (Bad Request)`

Here is my code:

> This is CategoryRequest Class

```
<?php

namespace App\Domain\Category\Request;


use App\Http\Requests\FormRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\JsonRequest;

class CategoryRequest extends JsonRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'category' => 'required',
            'status' => 'required'
        ];
    }
}
```

I'm extending it to JsonRequest class which I used to do in Laravel 5.4 and used to work properly.

> Here is JsonRequest Class

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

class JsonRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
    {
    $errors = (new ValidationException($validator))->errors();

    throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json([
        'success' => false,
        'errors' => $errors,
    ], JsonResponse::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY));
   }
}
```

But for laravel 5.5 its now not working. Any guide or help for this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you checked the official laravel docummentation before upgrading?

Comment: @PedroFaria99 I'm sorry this is my new project I did not upgrade, just started new project with Laravel 5.5

Comment: If you check the API of [FormRequest](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.html) for version 5.5 It doesn't have the `response()` method.

Comment: @linktoahref thanks, I also tried the above code ( I edited my jsonRequest ), but still not working :(. Any Idea?

Comment: Try this `protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator) { throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json($validator->errors(), 422)); }` instead of your `failedValidation` function.

Comment: What's the error while executing the above code?

Comment: @HirenGohel I did that only, just didn't run the foreach loop in what you did

Comment: Still you got `400 bad request` error?

Comment: @linktoahref, validations are working fine but in console I'm seeing this error 422 (Unprocessable Entity)

Comment: @HirenGohel got this 422 (Unprocessable Entity)

Comment: As per docs, If validation fails, a redirect response will be generated to send the user back to their previous location. The errors will also be flashed to the session so they are available for display. If the request was an AJAX request, a HTTP response with a 422 status code will be returned to the user including a JSON representation of the validation errors.

Comment: @Siddharth 422 is natural response code for invalid data and the errors. So i think you have a mistake in your rules may be with your request data!

Comment: @HirenGohel let me know whenever you are free, so that you can come to my team viewer and check it.

Comment: @Siddharth I just told you about `422 (Unprocessable Entity)` error. You can also check this URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34966690/error-422-unprocessable-entity-in-laravel-with-ajax  Hope it helps you! Lastly, you are my senior! :)

Comment: @HirenGohel being your senior :P doesn't mean that I know more than you

Comment: @linktoahref is it that until I get 422 code, I won't be able to catch it on ajax success function?

Comment: If you need to catch it on ajax success function, the response code should be 200. For 422 You could catch the error in the `ajax error handler`  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @linktoahref Thanks man, you are a Legend :) :)

Comment: It is interesting error. Your code is runned on my project. Just a little difference, i wrote abstract class for the JsonRequest.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
```

And use this to return Json data:

```
return new JsonResponse($variable);
```

Comment: Hi Kannan, thanks for the reply, could you please check whats wrong in my above code?